# How to test min/max length with Laravel Feature tests

Tags: laravel-5, tdd, laravel-5.8

I am trying to validate a feature test. Here is my controller:

```
$attributes = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required|max:2',
    'zip' => 'required|min:5',
]);

Location::create($attributes);

return redirect('/locations', 301);
```

I am saying that `state` can only have a max length of 2 characters.

My test looks like this:

```
$this->withExceptionHandling();
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$location = factory(Location::class)->raw(['state' => 'qwerty']);

$response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', $location);


$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertSessionHasErrors([
    'state' => 'The state may not be greater than 2 characters.'
]);
```

And that test will pass.

However if I change it to this:

```
...
$location = factory(Location::class)->raw(['state' => 'AZ']);
....
```

> Expected status code 302 but received 301.
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

It will fail. I am confused, since I *want* a 2 character state. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have also tried to add the `messages` method to my controller to return exactly that error message with no luck.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'state.max' => 'The state may not be greater than 2 characters.',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Only other side problem I see, is youre not validating its a valid state. If a user edits the drop down, or manually keys a state lik OO itll accept it. Ive done similar situations by creating a table that houses acceptable states, then validate that the submission matches. Then you can do something like value=WA and the option as Washington.

Comment: This may be irrelevant to your question. Have you tried doing dd dumps in each step to make sure things are being passed as anticipated?

Comment: This is a great callout Kray. My current tests would allow for the same. A state (could) be "OO" which is invalid. I'm just getting started with TDD, so that may have to wait. I will be using a dropdown, so most users shouldn't have a problem (hopefully). :)